# Flutter bloc data sharing with an update subscription

Tags: flutter, bloc

I have `Bloc A` and `Bloc B` and I need each of these blocs to have access to the `List<String> Items`. This is easy to organize, it is enough to create a `Repository class`, in which to place this `List<String> Items` and pass it to each of the blocs when they are created. The problem is that when updating the data in the repository from bloc A, bloc B does not know that the repository data has changed. Perhaps I did not understand and read the documentation poorly, but I did not find an answer to my problem there. How can I subscribe to changes in data from several blocks at once?

Comment: Make the repository a singleton, so both bloc access the same instance every time.

Comment: @Chance Singleton will add state tracking and subscription?  Passing the same repository instance for bloc A and block B is not a problem, I don’t understand how to make the behavior as in the `Provider` package when `notifyListeners()` updates the data of all subscribers. I am prompted below that I need to create streams and subscribe to them in order to receive automatic data updates in several blocks

Comment: No, it will not add, it would be necessary to work with streamController, then you will get what you want. Where it would issue an update whenever it changes and whoever is subscribed to the service would receive the update. But singlenton also needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, some are:

1. Common repository that expose methods providing streams to subscribe to in each bloc.
2. Connect blocs A and B via UI using BlocListeners and events.

Official documentation describes bloc to bloc communication here, which this is.

https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication